# 'pytesseract' module not found

Tags: python, module, python-tesseract

I am using visual studio code with the python extension installed on Ubuntu, I have created a python file named "image_extraction" and installed selenium, fuzzy-wuzzy, and other modules.

Everything works just fine except pytesseract despite that the terminal says that the pyterresract has been installed successfully

My python script:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

# Load image using Pillow library
image = Image.open('web_screenshot.png')

# Convert image to text using pytesseract library
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

# Print extracted text
print(text)
```

I get the below error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'

Steps taken by me to solve this till now:

I installed pytesseract in the virtual env using pip install pytesseract from inside that virtual environment (venv),

I looked into the "site-packages" folder (..\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\Lib\site-packages) and I do see that "pytesseract" folder does exist there along with "pytesseract-0.2.0.dist-info". Note that this is also the folder where I can see "selenium" and other modules that run perfectly fine.

I installed Pillow just to make sure.

I researched online for the same error and found solutions stating that I should pip install pytesseract and also check if pytesseract exists in my "site-packages" of the virtual env which I am trying to run in, both of which steps I have already taken.

I have also installed tesseract-OCR version 3.05.01, which is, by default, located in "C:\Program Files (x86)"

If I try to run pip install pytesseract again just below the "ModuleNotFoundError", I get the below message:

> Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in c:\users\stan\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages (0.2.0) Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\stan\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages (from pytesseract) (5.1.0)

I have also tried uninstalling pytesseract and manually deleting any file name containing pytesseract from the system and then installing pytesseract again.

Can anyone kindly suggest what I might be missing or point me in the direction where I can research this topic?

Is there any alternate way of installing pytesseract apart from `pip install`, which might help in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use explicitly the path in your code like:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
```